# How to store data in hive table from different file location

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hdfs

If we have multiple data sources and from each data source, one file is coming to HDFS but in a different location, how do we store all these files in a single Hive table?

Comment: Does that file always has the same name?

Comment: I suggest you work at a higher ingestion layer. For example, use Kafka or NiFi rather than write directly to HDFS. With those, you can define processes to re-route data and then build a unified Hive table

Comment: Yes file has the same name always

Answer (score 1):

Create an external table and for each path, add a partition and specify that location as the path for partition.